# Software for symbolic calculus?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, math-software, symbolic-computation

Its more of a reference than a question, recently i am doing too much integration within integration and derivatives within derivatives and limits of long string of functions and too much math for wolfram to handle on a laptop, so is there a better program for integration and derivatives and limits or is there something online that could handle and calculate a limit of long string of functions ?!

Comment: This is question best posed to our colleagues at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com. It would be nice to see a sample of the code to look for simplifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is a great open-source resource for doing all kinds of math.  It is freely available and you can try it in your browser [here](https://cocalc.com/?utm_source=sagemath.org&utm_medium=landingpage).  It helps if you know Python.

Comment: And there's truly a "try it" webpage (no registration), [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems), you will have the list of currently available  computer algebra systems, their cost and type of license.

**Maxima**, **SageMath** and **Mathics** are, at least in my opinion, very good choices for what you seem to need (all of them are free).